# Delete option doesn't appear for plugins

Tags: plugins, admin-menu

On the Plugins screen I have options to activate and deactivate plugins, but I no longer have the "Delete" option. I'm relatively sure the option appeared earlier.

Also, when I hover over "Plugins" on the admin menu I don't get the usual popup submenu showing "Install New / Add / Editor". And when I click the Plugins menu I don't see those submenu options either.

What's gone wrong?

FWIW, the client I'm working for is hosted at GoDaddy.

[image]

Comment: Are you running a single WordPress site, or a WordPress network? What is the user role for your current user?

Comment: Excellent deletion candidate. :D And thanks for sharing your aha moment. We need more of this.

Comment: @chip-bennett This is a single, self-hosted WordPress site on GoDaddy, and the user is an Admin.

Answer (score 6):

D'oh.

I fixed it, but I'll leave this question in case others have similar problems.

When copy/pasting various options into wp-config.php I accidentally included this setting, which I don't normally use:

```
// Overkill but FYI: disallows installation/updating of any theme or plugin
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

That produces the described problem, albeit by design.

Answer (score 3):

This help me a lot, actually I had 2 options active on my wp-config (never added them)

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

just set the mode to false and problem solve itself...

Answer (score 0):

5 years after but I guess I´ll add my 2 cents. Don´t choose the plugin option on the left bar menu. instead, go to the top left on your screen and hover on *my sites* and on that sub-menu then hover on *network admin* and choose plugins there. Once that is done you will get the missing sub menu option to *add new* and the *delete* option will also become available once again on the *activate, deactivate* sub menu as well. cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer Iliana, but that sounds like you're either hosted on Wordpress.com, or it's perhaps a multi-site installation? The OP is just asking about a standard GoDaddy WP installation.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. Somehow it was there and i have never put it myself.

Change `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);`  to
 `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false );`